# How to select only one value from database table column which contain multiple values

Tags: mysql

```
+------------+----------+
| MonitorIds | Username |
+------------+----------+
| 3,33       | mytest   |
+------------+----------+
```

This my db table.I want to select only 3 from MonitorIds ,how should I make the query?

Comment: Please be verbose. Describe what you are trying to do, where you are facing problems and what you have tried. Attach code examples if necessary.

Comment: I need to show MonitorIds value 3 from the column MonitorIds which have values 3,33.

Comment: if you have the same pattern `3,33` i.e. 2 numbers separated by comma then `select substring_index(MonitorIds,',',1) as MonitorIds` should do the job.

Comment: thanks .It is showing the value 3 but I need both value separately..like first 3 then 33

Comment: `select substring_index(MonitorIds,',',-1)` will show the 2nd value.

Comment: Yaah .Its working too.Is any other commands..like one command that will separate the values...e.g +------------+----------+
| MonitorIds | Username |
+------------+----------+
| 3       | mytest   |
+33-------mytest-----+----------+